# SQL Server 2008 R2: create login and user

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Windows authentication and VB.net.

I'm looking for help with a script where a new user through a front end add them self to the database by creating a new login on the server, and a user for a database on the server.

I want it such that the user add in his name and it will do the rest, so the script I assume must either use the `'sa'` account or some other account to create the new login and user.

I tried using a stored procedure but apparently it doesn't work with `CREATE LOGIN` etc.?

Can anyone advise please.

Comment: This actually sounds like a bad idea, in my opinion. if you're using AD credentials, it would seem better to use an AD group, and have that as a login; and then the application used a trusted connection. Then there no need for "Create login" process in the application, which *could* require the applications have more permissions than it needs.

Comment: I would start by suggesting you consider upgrading your database. 2008 (all versions) have been unsupported for several months now. Time to join the modern sql server folks. Next I would ask why you want an application to create new sql logins. That sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: FWIW, if you are deadset on creating a new login for each user you absolutely can use a stored procedure. You will just have to use dynamic sql inside your stored procedure for this to work.

Comment: OK, I agree its not a great idea, what I want is for users to register themsleves to save me doing it going forward.

Comment: Also I was thinking dynamic sql is the way to go or use an already approved user name in the vb.net connection string to authourise their setup!

Comment: I will have to move forward at some point to a more upto date sql version this is just for testing at the moment!

Comment: I am open to other suggestions too, if there a better way!

Comment: This has the sound of being a website. You do NOT want to have every single user create a new login to your sql database. That is not a great model. You would use a single sql login for the website. And then you manage users through the application. The way you are describing would mean you would need a service to check for a user. Then close that connection and create a new one for each user. This would defeat connection pooling and is just a nightmare to maintain. Your whole approach here needs to be redesigned.

Comment: Hi Sean that sounds fine, so its winform app which login would I use, do I add the login username and password in the connection string?